# Why does one String save to a file, whereas the other doesn't, with equivalent code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am successfully saving a string as the contents of a file in one instance, whereas in the other, it fails. Why?

Here is the code for the *successful* attempt (creates a file named "platypi.xml" with the contents from the original file, which is on a handheld device, into a new file on the server/PC):

```
public enum HttpMethods
{
    GET = 0,
    PUT,
    POST,
    DELETE,
    HEAD,
    OPTIONS,
    LIST,
    UNKNOWN
}

private void menuItem2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    String uri = "http://192.168.125.50:21608/api/inventory/sendXML/duckbill/platypus/platypi";
    RESTfulMethods rm = new RESTfulMethods();
    rm.SendXMLFile(uri);
}

public void SendXMLFile(string uri)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"\My Documents\heavens2Murgatroid.XML");
    String line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.Append(line); 
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    sr.Close();

    string strData = @sb.ToString();
    strData = strData.Replace("\"", "'"); // <= Needed?
    CreateRequestNoCredentials(uri, HttpMethods.POST, strData, "application/xml"); 
}

public static HttpWebRequest CreateRequestNoCredentials(string uri, HttpMethods method, string data, string contentType)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    try
    {
        request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();
        request.ContentType = contentType; 
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = contentType;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
        {
            byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
            using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.ContentLength = 0;
        }
        }
    catch (WebException webex)
    {
        HttpWebResponse hwr = (HttpWebResponse) webex.Response;
        HttpStatusCode hsc = hwr.StatusCode;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Status code == {1}", webex.Message, hsc.ToString()));
    }
    return request as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

Here is the code for the *unsuccessful* attempt:

```
// This code also uses the HttpMethods enum

public static void WriteIt2(string fileName, string data)
{
    // "data" does contain valid data here; fileName is also a valid name
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} exists - deleting", fileName));
        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
    string justFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    String uri = String.Format("http://192.168.125.50:21608/api/inventory/sendXML/duckbill/platypus/{0}", justFileName);
    String bla = data.Substring(0, 102);
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("uri is {0}; first part of data is {1}", uri, bla));
    // I do see the first part of data here in the MessageBox ("bla" and thus "data" are not empty)
    CreateRequestNoCredentials(uri, HttpMethods.POST, data, "application/xml"); 
}

// CreateRequestNoCredentials() is the same as that shown above
```

In this case, a file is saved (named "[fileName]"), but the file is empty. What could the difference be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I see is the first set of code passes an altered string literal into the CreateRequestNoCredentials() method. string strData = @sb.ToString(); Not sure what you are passing into the WriteIt2 method.

Comment: The WriteIt2() "magically" has a string passed in with the data; I don't know how it works. The code is as hard to understand as humanly possible.